# Jwplayer load new video without playing ads

Tags: jwplayer, ads, jwplayer6

I want `jwplayer` to load a new video without playing advertisement.

Here is what I set up `jwplayer`

```
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "/images/covers/movie.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: "rtmp://[wowza-ip]:1935/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:movie/movie.mp4", "default": true
    }]
}],
primary: "flash",
fallback: false,
flashplayer: "/jwplayer.flash.swf",
html5player: "/jwplayer.html5.js",
width: "854",
height: "480",
advertising: {
    client: "vast",
    schedule: {
        preroll: {
            offset: "pre",
            tag: "/api/get_video_ads.php?banner_id=9",
        }
    },
}});
```

When I use `jwplayer.load` it could play the `new_movie` but I still see the preroll advertising of jwplayer playing before the movie start.

```
var new_movie = "rtmp://[wowza-ip]:1935/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:movie/new_movie.mp4
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").load([{file : new_movie}]);
```

Can you help me stop the advertisement?

*sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Instead of doing load, why not just do a setup again with the new movie, but without adverting?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing load, why not just do a setup again with the new movie, but without adverting.

So you have your normal code:

```
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "/images/covers/movie.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: "rtmp://[wowza-ip]:1935/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:movie/movie.mp4", "default": true
    }]
}],
primary: "flash",
fallback: false,
flashplayer: "/jwplayer.flash.swf",
html5player: "/jwplayer.html5.js",
width: "854",
height: "480",
advertising: {
    client: "vast",
    schedule: {
        preroll: {
            offset: "pre",
            tag: "/api/get_video_ads.php?banner_id=9",
        }
    },
}});
```

So instead of using this code:

```
var new_movie = "rtmp://[wowza-ip]:1935/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:movie/new_movie.mp4
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").load([{file : new_movie}]);
```

Use this:

```
var new_movie = "rtmp://[wowza-ip]:1935/mediacache/_definst_/mp4:movie/new_movie.mp4
```

And this setup code:

```
jwplayer("jwplayer_container").setup({
playlist: [{
    image: "/images/covers/movie.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: new_movie, "default": true
    }]
}],
primary: "flash",
fallback: false,
flashplayer: "/jwplayer.flash.swf",
html5player: "/jwplayer.html5.js",
width: "854",
height: "480"
}});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I gonna try this and I will give you a feedback soon.